# UI update of recycler view and web sockets

Tags: android, kotlin, okhttp

How can I implement update UI with recyler view?. I have one recycler view and two view holders based on the side who sent. with name, data, time, read status. its a chat app and I'm using websockets to send thoes messages, I want to be able to update the UI once a new message has been sent or received . I'm using OkHttp to handle the API requests. I have edited the actual URL link. This is what I attempted but it wont show or update the UI

Thanks

```
class ChatActivity : AppCompatActivity(), CombinedChatsAdapter.ChatItemClickListener {
private lateinit var webSocketManager: WebSocketManager
private lateinit var clientRecyclerView: RecyclerView
private lateinit var adapter: CombinedChatsAdapter
private lateinit var messageEditText: EditText // Add this
private lateinit var rootView: View // Declare it at the class level
private var hcIdChat: Int? = null
private var serviceIDChat: Int? = null
private var chatHcWplace: String? = null
private var chatHcSerID: Int? = null
private var chatCreatorID: Int? = null
var storedUserName: String? = null
private lateinit var progressBar: ProgressBar


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat)

    progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progress_bar) // Initialize the ProgressBar

    rootView = window.decorView.rootView
    val slideInAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_in)
    val slideOutAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_out)

    clientRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_gchat)
    clientRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    val layoutManager = clientRecyclerView.layoutManager as LinearLayoutManager
    layoutManager.stackFromEnd = true
    adapter = CombinedChatsAdapter(mutableListOf(), this)
    clientRecyclerView.adapter = adapter

    storedUserName = SecurePreferencesManager.getUserName(this@ChatActivity)
    chatHcWplace = intent.getStringExtra("serviceHcW")//wplace
    chatHcSerID = intent.getIntExtra("hcServiceId", -1)
    chatCreatorID = intent.getIntExtra("creatorUserId", -1)
    hcIdChat = intent.getIntExtra("hcId", -1)
    serviceIDChat = intent.getIntExtra("serviceId", -1)//

    Log.d("ChatActivity", "chatHcWplace: $chatHcWplace")
    Log.d("ChatActivity", "chatHcSerID: $chatHcSerID")
    Log.d("ChatActivity", "chatCreatorID: $chatCreatorID")
    Log.d("ChatActivity", "hcIdChat: $hcIdChat")
    Log.d("ChatActivity", "hcServiceIDChat: $serviceIDChat")//

    if (chatHcSerID != -1 && chatCreatorID != -1) {
        fetchDataForChats(chatHcWplace.toString(), chatHcSerID!!, chatCreatorID!!)
        Log.d(
            "ClickedIdAndHcWplace",
            "chatHcSerID: $chatHcSerID, hcWplace: $chatHcWplace,creatorId:$chatCreatorID"
        )
    }

    val sendButton: MaterialButton = findViewById(R.id.button_gchat_send)
    val keyboardOpenClickListener = View.OnClickListener {
        messageEditText = findViewById(R.id.edit_gchat_message) // Initialize the EditText here

        val typedMessage = messageEditText.text.toString()
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        sen(chatCreatorID!!)
        messageEditText.text.clear()

    }
    val keyboardClosedClickListener = View.OnClickListener {
        // Handle the click action when the keyboard is closed
        // For example, show a voice recording interface
        // You can implement your desired behavior here
        Toast.makeText(this@ChatActivity, "Keyboard is closed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

    rootView.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(object :
        ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
        private var isKeyboardVisible = false

        override fun onGlobalLayout() {
            val rect = Rect()
            rootView.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(rect)
            val screenHeight = rootView.height
            val keypadHeight = screenHeight - rect.bottom

            val animateButtons = keypadHeight > screenHeight * 0.15

            val sendButtonIcon = if (animateButtons) {
                R.drawable.send_button_default // Set the keyboard open icon
            } else {
                R.drawable.voice_button_keyboard // Set the keyboard closed icon
            }
            sendButton.icon = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this@ChatActivity, sendButtonIcon)

            if (animateButtons) {
                sendButton.setOnClickListener(keyboardOpenClickListener)
            } else {
                sendButton.setOnClickListener(keyboardClosedClickListener)
            }

            isKeyboardVisible = animateButtons
        }
    })



}


fun generateUniqueMessageId(): String {
    val currentTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis()
    val randomSuffix = (currentTimeMillis % 1000000000000).toString().padStart(13, '0')

    return randomSuffix
}

private fun sen(userId: Int) {
    val url = "wss/wss?userId=$userId"
    val httpUrl =
        url.replaceFirst("^http:".toRegex(), "ws:").replaceFirst("^https:".toRegex(), "wss:")
    Log.d("http", httpUrl)
    val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .readTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .build()
    val request = Request.Builder()
        .url(httpUrl)
        .build()
    Log.d("req", "$request")
    val wsListener = EchoWebSocketListener()

    val webSocket = client.newWebSocket(request, wsListener)

    var messageObj = MessageObject(
        CreatorUserName = storedUserName!!,
        Text = messageEditText.text.toString(),
        HCServiceId = chatHcSerID!!,
        HC_WPLACE = chatHcWplace!!,
        HCId = hcIdChat!!,
        CreatorUserId = chatCreatorID!!,
        MessageTypeId = 1,
        IsSentByCitizen = true,
        ServiceId = serviceIDChat!!,
        clientSideMessageId = Date().getTime().toString(),
    )
    Log.d("message", "$messageObj")


    Log.d("tag2hcCreatorUserName", "$storedUserName")
    Log.d("tag2hcServiceIDChat", "$serviceIDChat")
    Log.d("tag2chatHcWplace", "$chatHcWplace")
    Log.d("tag2hcIdChat", "$hcIdChat")
    Log.d("tag2chatCreatorID", "$chatCreatorID")
    Log.d("tag2chatHcSerID", "$chatHcSerID")
    if (messageObj != null) {
        val gson = Gson()
        val messageJson = gson.toJson(messageObj)
        Log.d("message", "$messageJson")
        webSocket.send(messageJson)

        val newChatsItem = ChatsItem(
            creatorUserName = messageObj.CreatorUserName,
            text = messageObj.Text,
            hcServiceId=messageObj.HCServiceId,
            hC_WPLACE=messageObj.HC_WPLACE,
            hcId=messageObj.HCId,
            creatorUserId=messageObj.CreatorUserId,
            isSentByCitizen=messageObj.IsSentByCitizen,
            serviceId=messageObj.ServiceId,
            clientSideMessageId = messageObj.clientSideMessageId,
            MessageTypeId = 1
        )
        runOnUiThread {
            Log.d("sen", "Adding message to adapter")
            adapter.addMessage(newChatsItem)
            Log.d("sen", "Notifying adapter")
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() // Ensure that the adapter knows data has changed
        }
    } else {
        Log.d("tag2", "MessageObject is null")
    }
}

class EchoWebSocketListener() : WebSocketListener() {
    override fun onOpen(webSocket: WebSocket, response: Response) {
        Log.d("WebSocket", "WebSocket connection opened") // Add this log message

    }

    override fun onMessage(webSocket: WebSocket, text: String) {
        Log.d("WebSocket Receiving : ", text!!)

    }

    override fun onMessage(webSocket: WebSocket, bytes: ByteString) {
        output("WebSocket Receiving bytes : " + bytes!!.hex())
    }

    override fun onClosing(webSocket: WebSocket, code: Int, reason: String) {
        webSocket!!.close(NORMAL_CLOSURE_STATUS, null)
        Log.d("WebSocket Closing :"," $code / $reason")
    }

    override fun onFailure(webSocket: WebSocket, t: Throwable, response: Response?) {
        Log.d("WebSocket Error : " , t.message!!)
    }

    companion object {
        private val NORMAL_CLOSURE_STATUS = 1000
    }

    private fun output(txt: String) {
        Log.d("WSS", txt)
    }
}
data class ChatsItem(
var id: Int?=null,
var creatorUserName: String,
var text: String,
var serviceId: Int,
var recipientUserId: Int?=null,
var recipientUserName: String?=null,
var hcServiceId: Int,
var hC_ArName: String?=null,
var hC_EnName: String?=null,
var hcId: Int,
var hC_WPLACE: String,
var creatorUserId: Int,
var isSentByCitizen: Boolean,
var creationTime: String?=null,
var voice: String?=null,
var clientSideMessageId:String?,
var MessageTypeId:Int?
)


class CombinedChatsAdapter(
private val chatList: MutableList<ChatsItem>,
private val itemClickListener: ChatItemClickListener
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

companion object {
    private const val VIEW_TYPE_CLIENT = 1
    private const val VIEW_TYPE_PROVIDER = 2
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): 
 RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    return when (viewType) {
        VIEW_TYPE_CLIENT -> {
            val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                .inflate(R.layout.me_perspective_layout, parent, false)
            ClientViewHolder(itemView)
        }

        VIEW_TYPE_PROVIDER -> {
            val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                .inflate(R.layout.other_perspective, parent, false)
            ProviderViewHolder(itemView)
        }

        else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown view type")
    }
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val chatsItem = chatList[position]

    when (holder) {
        is ClientViewHolder -> holder.bindClient(chatsItem)
        is ProviderViewHolder -> holder.bindProvider(chatsItem)
    }
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return chatList.size
}

override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
    val chatsItem = chatList[position]
    return if (chatsItem.isSentByCitizen) {
        VIEW_TYPE_CLIENT
    } else {
        VIEW_TYPE_PROVIDER
    }
}

inner class ClientViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    init {
        itemView.setOnClickListener {
            val clickedChat = chatList[adapterPosition]
            itemClickListener.onItemClick(clickedChat)
        }
    }

    fun bindClient(chatsItem: ChatsItem) {
        val (dateString, timeString) = separateDateAndTime(chatsItem)

        itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.text_gchat_date_me).text =
            dateString
        itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.text_gchat_message_me).text =
            chatsItem.text
        itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.text_gchat_timestamp_me).text =
            timeString


        Log.d(
            "ClientViewHolder",
            "chattime: ${chatsItem.creationTime}, text: ${chatsItem.text}, date: $dateString"
        )
    }
}
fun addMessage(item: ChatsItem) {
    chatList.add(item)
    notifyItemInserted(chatList.size - 1)
}
inner class ProviderViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    init {
        itemView.setOnClickListener {
            val clickedChat = chatList[adapterPosition]
            itemClickListener.onItemClick(clickedChat)
        }
    }

    fun bindProvider(chatsItem: ChatsItem) {
        val (dateString, timeString) = separateDateAndTime(chatsItem)

        itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.text_gchat_date_other).text = dateString
        itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.text_gchat_message_other).text = chatsItem.text
        itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.text_gchat_user_other).text =
            chatsItem.creatorUserName
        itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.text_gchat_timestamp_other).text = timeString

        Log.d(
            "ProviderViewHolder",
            "chattime: ${chatsItem.creationTime}, text: ${chatsItem.text}, date: $dateString"
        )
    }
}

interface ChatItemClickListener {
    fun onItemClick(chatsItem: ChatsItem)
}

private fun separateDateAndTime(chatsItem: ChatsItem): Pair<String, String> {
    // Your date and time separation logic here
    val inputFormat = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSS", Locale.getDefault())
    val outputDateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.getDefault())
    val outputTimeFormat = SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault())

    val parsedDate: Date = inputFormat.parse(chatsItem.creationTime) ?: Date()
    val dateString = outputDateFormat.format(parsedDate)
    val timeString = outputTimeFormat.format(parsedDate)

    return Pair(dateString, timeString)
  }
}
```